# Character to date with as.Date

Tags: r, date, character

I have a vector (length=1704) of character like this:

```
[1] "1871_01" "1871_02" "1871_03" "1871_04" "1871_05" "1871_06" "1871_07" "1871_08" "1871_09" "1871_10" "1871_11" "1871_12"
[13] "1872_01" "1872_02" "1872_03" ...
.
.
.
[1681] "2011_01" "2011_02" "2011_03" "2011_04" "2011_05" "2011_06" "2011_07" "2011_08" "2011_09" "2011_10" "2011_11" "2011_12"
[1693] "2012_01" "2012_02" "2012_03" "2012_04" "2012_05" "2012_06" "2012_07" "2012_08" "2012_09" "2012_10" "2012_11" "2012_12"
```

I want to convert this vector into a vector of dates.
For that I use:

```
as.Date(vector, format="%Y_%m")
```

But it returns "NA"
I tried for one value:

```
b <- "1871_01"
as.Date(b, format="%Y_%m")
[1] NA
strptime(b, "%Y_%m")
[1] NA
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work...
Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: A Date must have a day.  Append a day to each string or don't use "Date" class in the first place.  "yearmon" class in zoo package can handle year/month with no day directly.

Comment: Ok thanks! I added _01 to each string

Answer (score 1):

If you do regular work in year+month format, the `zoo` package can come in handy since it treats `yearmon` as a first class citizen (and is compatible with `Date` objects/functions):

```
library(zoo)

my.ym <- as.yearmon("1871_01", format="%Y_%m")

print(my.ym)
## [1] "Jan 1871"

str(my.ym)
## Class 'yearmon'  num 1871

my.date <- as.Date(my.date)

print(my.date)
## [1] "1871-01-01"

str(my.date)
## Date[1:1], format: "1871-01-01"
```